# Discord.py Calculator: Multiple Values?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, calculator

My current code is limited to only taking in two values. without going through the entire alphabet, is there a way for me to take in more than two values and use them? Thank you.

```
   @client.command() 
async def add(ctx,a:int,b:int): 
    await ctx.send(f"{a} + {b} = {a+b}") #Adds A and B

@client.command() 
async def sub(ctx,a:int,b:int): 
    await ctx.send(f"{a} - {b} = {a-b}") #Subtracts A and B

@client.command() 
async def multiply(ctx,a:int,b:int): 
    await ctx.send(f"{a} * {b} = {a*b}") #Multplies A and B

@client.command() 
async def divide(ctx,a:int,b:int): 
    await ctx.send(f"{a} / {b} = {a/b}") #Divides A and B
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `*` for putting all the values in one variable, this variable will be a list. Then, you can do:

```py
@client.command() 
async def add(ctx, *nums):
    operation = " + ".join(nums)
    await ctx.send(f'{operation} = {eval(operation)}')

@client.command() 
async def sub(ctx, *nums): 
    operation = " - ".join(nums)
    await ctx.send(f'{operation} = {eval(operation)}')

@client.command() 
async def multiply(ctx, *nums): 
    operation = " * ".join(nums)
    await ctx.send(f'{operation} = {eval(operation)}')

@client.command() 
async def divide(ctx, *nums): 
    operation = " / ".join(nums)
    await ctx.send(f'{operation} = {eval(operation)}')
```

Or you can create just one command named `calculate`, it'll probably be more useful.

```
@client.command()
async def calculate(ctx, operation, *nums):
    if operation not in ['+', '-', '*', '/']
        await ctx.send('Please type a valid operation type.')
    var = f' {operation} '.join(nums)
    await ctx.send(f'{var} = {eval(var)}')
```

With this command, user also has to type the operation type.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to separate the operations and the numbers just need to identify the maths question as a string and eval do the heavy lifting. Sorry for the late answer.

```
@client.command()
async def calc(ctx, operation:str):
  await ctx.send(eval(operation))
```

This code only works assuming your client is defined.
Heres an example:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!!")
```

Comment: Also forgot to mention that this only works if the command in discord has no spaces

Comment: an easy fix for that limitation would be to just `.replace(' ','')` on the string `operation` before evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

My way is simple, but for power you need to do ** instead of ^
Also if your code is like

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "prefix")
```

You should do

```
@bot.command()
async def math(ctx, *, expression:str):
    calculation = eval(expression)
    await ctx.send('Math: {}\nAnswer: {}'.format(expression, calculation))
```

But if it is like

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "prefix")
```

^ It says client instead of bot you should change the @bot.command() into a @client.command(), but I'm pretty sure a lot of people know that so just copy the code.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the other answers, passing `*arg` as an argument would consume all the rest of the arguments passed and provide you with a tuple.

Since using `eval` openly is dangerous, I recommend parsing your expression manually.

If you want a more easier solution, you can use an external module to do this for you such as  [SimpleEval](https://pypi.org/project/simpleeval/).

Here's a simple implementation of an 'add' command using `*argument`:

```py
def add_numbers(numbers: tuple):
    if operator == "+":

        # escape all empty strings if any
        numbers_escaped = list(filter(None, numbers))

        # numbers is a tuple of str
        # We should make them all ints first, so we can perform addition
        numbers = list(map(int, numbers_escaped))

        # Now, we can return the addition result
        result = sum(numbers)
        
        return result


@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, operator: str,  *numbers):
    output = add_numbers(numbers)
    await ctx.send(f"Your result is: {output}")
```

Answer (score 0):

@client.command()
async def multiply(ctx, num1: int, num2: int):
a = num1*num2
await ctx.send(f"the answer is {a}")

@client.command()
async def add(ctx, num1: int, num2: int):
a = num1+num2
await ctx.send(f"the answer is {a}")

@client.command()
async def subtract(ctx, num1: int, num2: int):
a = num1-num2
await ctx.send(f"the answer is {a}")

@client.command()
async def devide(ctx, num1: int, num2: int):
a = num1/num2
await ctx.send(f"the answer is {a}")

try using this instead

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).